# Singleton class

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

We have an application, where to access the the config file, we have a singleton class and object of this is used.

I understand that singleton class is good and provide only one instance of the object. 
My Question is why we can't have Opening and closing of the config file whenever it is required.

Ofcourse, this method may be expensive since Windows need to allot a handle and dispose it off when it is not in use.

Are there any Specific reason for using singleton class.

Thank you,
Harsha

Comment: "I understand that singleton class is good" You must be new to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton class can be pure evil. It usually is. You'll see it if you ever decide to apply loose-coupling to your code.

My advice is to reconsider your design. Think of reading config file at application start and persisting an object with configuration parameters in memory. Then you can pass the object to classes/interfaces that require config parameters.

You may also redesign your application in a way that it doesn't require numerous writes to the config file without using singleton (anti)pattern.

Comment: your approach, popular as it is, has the downside of needing to drag your config object through many classes, some of which may even not need it at all, just so they can pass it to objects they instantiate. This pollutes the interfaces and is not elegant, IMHO

Comment: I can understand what you mean. Even though you can hide your class behind many interfaces (IConnectionConfigParameters, IOtherParameters) and pass each "interface" to appropriate class.
I know this solution is not perfect, although it's far more better than using singleton (I've experienced it how painful can it be to remove singleton class).

However you may use config file directly, provided that each assembly reads its own config file (app.config/web.config).

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question somehow backwards :)
**Why to use singleton class**. First thing to note is that singleton class is perhaps the most missused design pattern in software development. But it has it's advantages and in your case I think it is usable. If your application uses the config file extensively it's usually good idea to make it Singleton. It would be pain to pass config file object everywhere. This is also answer to anybody who argues with "loose coupling" or TDD. Because if your application is logically coupled with config file you just have to use it and test it with config file. On top of that your Singleton can return different (mock) instances for tests which gives you nice encapsulation.

**Why we can't have Opening and closing of the config file whenever it is required.** Well you can with singleton. Singleton pattern imposes restrictions to OO design (1 instance of object). It just means that programmer is able to call anywhere in the code something like: ConfigSingleton.Instance.GetDefaultFontColor(); The inner workings of this object are totally encapsulated. If you like you can open the file each time programmer calls GetDefaultFontColor. Or you can reread config file on some kind of event (file change) and store it in your memory.

To rephrase last paragraph: "the fact that you are using singleton pattern doesn't say anything about how and when you: open, read, close, write into your config file.